# how to require publickey and otp, or password and otp when logging in with ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, pam, google

I'm trying to get ssh to work in a way where password auth can be skipped with a key, and in addition every login would be followed up with totp using google's libpam on my new debian 9 installation.

So far i've been able to get the first part working, where if i provide a key, the server asks me for the otp, but the way it is, i've had to comment out both `@include common-auth` and `@include common-password` to suppress the password prompt in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`.

Seems obvious then that if i do
`AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive:pam password,keyboard-interactive:pam` in my sshd_config and i try logging in without a key it does not matter what password i provide since the password checking parts are commented out.

The logical way to solve this as it would seem to a novice like me, would be that i could define different pam methods or classes, and then somehow reference those in my sshd_config, but i cant seem to find any information regarding such an operation.

**Is it even possible to accomplish this particular combo?**

*edit 1:*

Tinkering further with this, it really does not make as much sense as i initially thought. 
If i comment out both `@include common-auth` and `@include common-password`, i can get `publickey,keyboard-interactive:pam` to not ask for password. If i now set `AuthenticationMethods password` for a specific user, that user is not able to log in at all due to every password being rejected, even if it really is the valid one. So logically then it seems sshd `password` auth method also uses the `/etc/pam.d/sshd` configs. 
if i dont comment those includes, `keyboard-interactive:pam` asks for password and verification code, but `password` auth method still fails for any user that has otp initialized (and would fail for all except i give google libpam the nullok option). Seems like `password` is just a crappy version of `keyboard-interactive:pam` that can only prompt for one input and thus always fails if there are more then one required inputs.

**If i write my own pam.d module, is there any way to make ssh use it instead of `/etc/pam.d/sshd`?**

*edit 2:*

Im starting to think that i cant do `(password && otp) || (publickey && otp)`, because the public key is checked in a different place from the rest, and so unless i can define which pam config to use with `AuthenticationMethods`, or i can somehow send parameters/arguments to the pam module, knowing when to check both and when to only check otp seems impossible

Comment: Is this on Ubuntu? The distributions each have their own schemes of generating PAM configs.

Comment: @john-mahowald ah, sorry for leaving out such a basic detail. This is Debian 9

Answer (score 1):

The problem stems from PAM and it almost makes it impossible.

The core problem is that the publickey stuff is handled by the ssh daemon, while keyboard-interactive is always handled by PAM (and password is also often handled by PAM depending on configuration). So there's no way for PAM to know whether or not a publickey has been set, and there's no way for ssh to be configured to optionally choose different AuthenticationMethods depending on whether or not publickey was used.

BUT ssh does set an environment variable, SSH_AUTH_INFO_0, when a publickey has been set and verified as approved, and PAM can see this variable. So what you do is write a pam_exec script that exits differently depending on whether or not SSH_AUTH_INFO_0 is set to something or not. And that pam_exec can use success=1 to skip one line (or more if needed, the code on RHEL8 was already spaghetti code before I got to modifying it which did make things more complicated).

I used a perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

if ($ENV{'SSH_AUTH_INFO_0'} =~ /^publickey /) {
  exit(0);
} else {
  exit(1);
}
```

And it was called with this line (success=2 was because of the pre-existing code, I had to skip a pam_deny that followed the pam_sss.so (which was "sufficient" and didn't hit the deny). Whether you use "ignore" or "ok" depends on the rest of your PAM stack for sshd. (And also you may be able to use "success=done" in some situations, if you're prompting for the OTP before the password, although I wasn't able to get that to work when I thought it should.)

```
auth        [success=2 default=ignore]                       pam_exec.so quiet /usr/local/sbin/ssh-pubkey-check
```

You also need to have this somewhat odd line set in your sshd_config:

```
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive keyboard-interactive
```

It first tries publickey plus keyboard-interactive. If that succeeds, PAM will pick up from the environment variable that it can skip password prompt altogether. If it fails (because no publickey was provided) it next tries only keyboard-interactive, but in this case PAM will prompt for both the OTP (left as an exercise for the student) and the password prompt.

There is more to it than this but it all depends on what your existing PAM setup looks like, and what you're authenticating against (local password file, LDAP, NIS, whatever) so I can't provide a one-size-fits-all solution.

Also note that using an environment variable to control the authentication steps feels janky, and theoretically could lead to an exploit where only an OTP is require and no other token. Although in every case I can think of, if someone can remotely or locally set an environment variable that PAM sees when called from sshd, then your system has already been hosed and this isn't an additional risk.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter you are looking for in the sshd_config is `AuthenticationMethods`.
I wrote a [blog post](https://www.privacyidea.org/ssh-keys-and-otp-really-strong-two-factor-authentication/) about combinting SSH key authentication with OTP a while ago.

However, this blog post uses the OTP with a pam module against the privacyIDEA authentication system. But you should be able to easily exchange this with the google pam.

Comment: I believe i've seen that blog post before. I Feel the main part is where you write your `common-auth-pi` and replace the unix password check with a privacyidea credential check. i dont know what `optional    pam_cap.so` does tho, i might be mistaken. 

But in the end you wind up always requiring a ssh key, which is not my goal

Comment: OK, so I misunderstood you. I think it is not possible to _optionally_ require and _additional_ sshkey.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many other layers of security and just want this one thing for a single account/key combo, you can try this dirty hack... It is a really bad idea and you shouldn't do it. A few of the obvious risks will be listed at the bottom. But if you are just tinkering in a highly isolated test network with zero risk, I guess you could try this:

Get yourself set up for `(password && otp) || (publickey)` as in many tutorials like [this one](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/configure-ssh-2fa). Then add a forced command to your publickey method which verifies OTP.

In `.ssh/authorized_keys` prepend your key like this:

```
restrict,pty,command="/usr/local/bin/promptOtpShell" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2E...
```

Then, in `/usr/local/bin/promptOtpShell`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -n "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" ]; then
    logger -p auth.error -t ${0##*/} "error: OTP: Subsystem refused for ${LOGNAME} from ${SSH_CLIENT%% *}"
    exit 1
fi
retry=3
key=$(head -1 ~/.google_authenticator)
while [ "$retry" -gt 0 ]; do
    read -p "OTP: " -n 6 -t 120 -s otp
    echo
    if echo -e "$key\n$otp" | oathtool -b --totp -w 2 - - >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        exec -la "${SHELL##*/}" "$SHELL"
    fi
    ((retry-=1))
done
logger -p auth.error -t ${0##*/} "error: OTP: Authentication failure for ${LOGNAME} from ${SSH_CLIENT%% *}"
```

Be sure to `apt install oathtool` and don't forget to `chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/promptOtpShell`.

**Risks**:

1. Environment variables are trusted more than is safe
2. Port, Agent and X11 forwarding will be permitted before OTP verification if enabled (which is why we `restrict` in this example)
3. If you adapt this approach for use from an `/etc/sshd_config` ForceCommand rather than `.ssh/authorized_keys` then you have to restrict all forwarding for any matching connections
4. Someone clever could almost certainly list another handful of issues in 20 minutes or less