# How to configure PAM to authenticate SSH logins with (password & OTP) or (public key & OTP)

Tags: ssh, pam, ubuntu-18.04, google-authenticator

My goal is to develop an ansible playbook to deploy multifactor ssh logins of the type `(public key and OTP) or (password and OTP)` on Ubuntu Server 18.04 hosts.

I followed the guide [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multi-factor-authentication-for-ssh-on-ubuntu-16-04) and it largely works. The only issue I had was needing to add `auth required pam_permit.so` to the end of `/etc/pam.d/sshd` in order to bypass OTP checks for users without a `~/.google_authenticator` file.

This guide is set up to use `AuthenticationMethods publickey,password publickey,keyboard-interactive` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` which requires a public key for all logins, while the MFA scheme I am trying to implement would allow a password with OTP. However, any other permutation of `AuthenticationMethods` seems to break authentication completely.

For example, `AuthenticationMethods password,keyboard-interface` allows users with a `~/.google_authenticator` file to login only if they enter in a correct OTP twice in a row, and will allow users without a `~/.google_authenticator` file to log in with any string entered as the password.

I've played with a ton of options, but I'm starting to think this type of configuration is impossible (see a similar post [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/939490/how-to-require-publickey-and-otp-or-password-and-otp-when-logging-in-with-ssh)). Why is that the case? I'm becoming more convinced that PAM is the culprit here, but I don't understand why `AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interface password,keyboard-interface` doesnt work out of the box

Here is my `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
# PAM configuration for the Secure Shell service

# Standard Un*x authentication.
# Commented out by me @include common-auth

# Disallow non-root logins when /etc/nologin exists.
account    required     pam_nologin.so

# Uncomment and edit /etc/security/access.conf if you need to set complex
# access limits that are hard to express in sshd_config.
# account  required     pam_access.so

# Standard Un*x authorization.
@include common-account

# SELinux needs to be the first session rule.  This ensures that any
# lingering context has been cleared.  Without this it is possible that a
# module could execute code in the wrong domain.
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_s$

# Set the loginuid process attribute.
session    required     pam_loginuid.so

# Create a new session keyring.
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke

# Standard Un*x session setup and teardown.
@include common-session

# Print the message of the day upon successful login.
# This includes a dynamically generated part from /run/motd.dynamic
# and a static (admin-editable) part from /etc/motd.
session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic
session    optional     pam_motd.so noupdate

# Print the status of the user's mailbox upon successful login.
session    optional     pam_mail.so standard noenv # [1]

# Set up user limits from /etc/security/limits.conf.
session    required     pam_limits.so

# Read environment variables from /etc/environment and
# /etc/security/pam_env.conf.
session    required     pam_env.so # [1]
# In Debian 4.0 (etch), locale-related environment variables were moved to
# /etc/default/locale, so read that as well.
session    required     pam_env.so user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale

# SELinux needs to intervene at login time to ensure that the process starts
# in the proper default security context.  Only sessions which are intended
# to run in the user's context should be run after this.
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so open

# Standard Un*x password updating.
@include common-password

### Added by me ###
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok
auth required pam_permit.so
```

and my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.101 2017/03/14 07:19:07 djm Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)

### changed by me ###----------------------------------------------------------------
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

### Added by me ###------------------------------------------------------------------
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive password,keyboard-interactive

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Comment: In the meantime, have you found a way to configure your SSHD so that this is possible? Just trying to achieve the same as you?

Answer (score 1):

The problem stems from PAM and it *almost* makes it impossible.

The core problem is that the publickey stuff is handled by the ssh daemon, while keyboard-interactive is always handled by PAM (and password is also often handled by PAM depending on configuration).  So there's no way for PAM to know whether or not a publickey has been set, and there's no way for ssh to be configured to optionally choose different AuthenticationMethods depending on whether or not publickey was used.

BUT ssh *does* set an environment variable, SSH_AUTH_INFO_0, when a publickey has been set and verified as approved, and PAM can see this variable.  So what you do is write a pam_exec script that exits differently depending on whether or not SSH_AUTH_INFO_0 is set to something or not.  And that pam_exec can use success=1 to skip one line (or more if needed, the code on RHEL8 was already spaghetti code before I got to modifying it which did make things more complicated).

I used a perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

if ($ENV{'SSH_AUTH_INFO_0'} =~ /^publickey /) {
  exit(0);
} else {
  exit(1);
}
```

And it was called with this line (success=2 was because of the pre-existing code, I had to skip a pam_deny that followed the pam_sss.so (which was "sufficient" and didn't hit the deny).  Whether you use "ignore" or "ok" depends on the rest of your PAM stack for sshd.  (And also you may be able to use "success=done" in some situations, if you're prompting for the OTP before the password, although I wasn't able to get that to work when I thought it should.)

```
auth        [success=2 default=ignore]                       pam_exec.so quiet /usr/local/sbin/ssh-pubkey-check
```

You also need to have this somewhat odd line set in your sshd_config:

```
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive keyboard-interactive
```

It first tries publickey plus keyboard-interactive.  If that succeeds, PAM will pick up from the environment variable that it can skip password prompt altogether.  If it fails (because no publickey was provided) it next tries only keyboard-interactive, but in this case PAM will prompt for both the OTP  (left as an exercise for the student) and the password prompt.

There is more to it than this but it all depends on what your existing PAM setup looks like, and what you're authenticating against (local password file, LDAP, NIS, whatever) so I can't provide a one-size-fits-all solution.

Also note that using an environment variable to control the authentication steps feels janky, and theoretically could lead to an exploit where only an OTP is require and no other token.  Although in every case I can think of, if someone can remotely or locally set an environment variable that PAM sees when called from sshd, then your system has already been hosed and this isn't an additional risk.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that "pam_permit.so" is a dangerous module to implement.

I think you are contradicting your two rules by saying:

> auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok

versus

> auth required pam_permit.so

It should be sufficient to use the "nullok" keyword to achieve what you are trying to do. A user without google-authentication set up can log in just the same, while the others need to enter the verification code.
*AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive* inside the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file would be just fine.

Furthermore you have 2 options to try out:
Either list the users in the file : **/etc/authusers**
which you can later refer to in **/etc/pam.d/sshd**

> auth sufficient pam_securid.so

> auth required   pam_deny.so

> auth requisite  pam_listfile.so item=user sense=allow
> file=/etc/authusers

...or use user groups:

**/etc/pam.d/sshd**

> auth [success=done default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup "groupname_here"